# dojo dijit _HasDropDown LazyLoading

Tags: lazy-loading, dojo

I was watching the Documentation on [`Dynamic & lazy-loading drop-downs`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/_HasDropDown.html#dynamic-lazy-loading-drop-downs) .
It looks like `loadDropDown: function(callback){...}` is only necessary and `isLoaded()` can be any arbitrary function like `isPresent()` or something else. as `loadDropDown` is the only person to call it.

If the `DropDown Widget` is no Loaded some `dropDown.refresh()` is Called which can even be an arbitrary method. any method that loads the data on dropdown and reports as `loaded`

and Once loaded `|` If already loaded the callback supplied is called.

My Question is Who calls the `loadDropDown()` ? and Whats the job of the `callback` ? as `dropDown.refresh()` has already loadded the dropdown.

In My Case I've an `data-dojo-attach-event="onkeyup: suggest"` in my `templateString` and this `suggest` function calls `loadDropDown()` with an empty callback.where `dropDown` is a `dijit._WidgetBase` derived `div, ul, li` based widget that never comes up. But it is created. and shows up in `console.log()` but then auto destroyed.I donno Why.

and where comes this `href` attribute ? How comes the `href` attribute be mandatory for a dropdown ?